# Evaluate the determinant of a rank-1 matrix plus $I$

Tags: linear-algebra

let $a_1, .......a_n \in \mathbb{R}$. Evaluate  the determinant

$\begin{bmatrix} 1+a_1 &a_2 &....&a_n\\a_1 & 1+a_2 &....&a_n \\...&...&....&...\\a_1 &a_2& ....&1 +a_n \end{bmatrix}$

First  i take $2\times2$ matrix A =$\begin{bmatrix} 1+a_1 &a_2 \\ a_1&1 +a_2 \end{bmatrix}$

As Determinant of $A = (1+a_1)(1+a_2) -a_1a_2= 1+a_2+a_1a_2 -a_1a_2= 1+ a_1 + a_2$

I don't  know  how  find the determinant  of $n\times n$ matrix.

Any hints/solution

thanks u

Comment: Note that your computation for the $2 \times 2$ case has a mistake.

Comment: okks @angryavian

Comment: @angryavian..i have edits  its now,,,thanks for pointing outs my mistakes